# X86 instruction format according to SDM

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, instruction-set

I see the following instruction format description of `ADD` according to X86 SDM manual.

[image]

This is somehow different from what I have seen before in 8086 instruction format. There we have

```
OPCODE  |  DIRECTION | WIDTH         MOD | REG | R/M
  6           1          1            2     3     3
```

According to the figure, if we assume `04` as a one byte instruction code, then it will be `00000100`. I guess `Ib` is the immediate byte. Therefore, the second byte will be the immediate number.

Sound confusing. Any comment?

Comment: Yes, it's different. x86 has various formats. Luckily you don't have to guess because the SDM has a whole _CHAPTER 2 INSTRUCTION FORMAT_ and also section _3.1 INTERPRETING THE INSTRUCTION REFERENCE PAGES_

Comment: OK. Also according to the manual `Adds the destination operand (first operand) and the source operand (second operand) and then stores the result
in the destination operand`. As I execute `__asm__("add %ecx, %eax");` I see that the value of eax is changed and not ecx.

Comment: GDB shows `01 c8   add    %ecx,%eax`. The opcode is `000000,0,1 11,001,000`. I see in the manual that 001 is ecx and 000 is eax. Therefore, ecx is considered as the source operand. It should be destination.

Comment: at&t syntax has operands reversed. Switch your tools to intel syntax (`gcc -masm=intel` and `set disassembly-flavor intel` in `gdb`).

Comment: The OPCODE 06 is the instruction `PUSH ES`.

Comment: @SirJoBlack the 6 means 6 bits there, it's not an actual value.

Comment: Ops, Excuse me, I had read wrong!

Comment: The instructions in your question are the special short-form AL/AX/EAX/RAX, immediate form with no ModRM byte: the accumulator destination is implicit.  See [What is the significance of operations on the register EAX having their own opcodes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38019386) and  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160739) for some x86 history about why 8086 dedicated extra opcodes to AL/AX short forms of immediate instructions.